# Rails: What is the correct way of saving the time of a video?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is a time span for every video. For example, for every youtube video, the time it last may be 4minutes or 30s.

The problem is how shold I save it into database?

Just store it as a `string` like `4:30`? Or change it to seconds and store it as an `integer`? Then how can I change it back to `minute:second` format?

An additonal note:

Now I'm making a video congrugator, so the time actually come in as `seconds: 30`, or just in plain format like `4:30`, then how can I turn the latter format into seconds integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way of keeping time depends of you business logic.
I would prefer to keep length in seconds, and then convert to minutes, hours and so on.
You can easily do it by simple devision:

```
minutes = (seconds / 60)
seconds_left = (seconds % 40)
human_time = "#{minutes}:#{seconds_left}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Time class to parse your time string.

```
require 'date' # Only needed outside of rails!
require 'active_support/all' # Only needed outside of rails!

video_length = "04:30"

# This ensures the format of video_length is HH:MM:SS
def hours_minutes_seconds(str) 
    parts = str.split(':').reverse
    len = parts.length
    if ! parts.length || parts.length > 3
        raise("bad input (#{str}) for hours_minutes_seconds") and return
    end
    (0..2).map do |i|
        part = parts[len -i]
        part || "00"
    end.join(':')
end

#Remember how unix time starts at 1 Jan 1970?
time = DateTime.iso8601( "1970-01-01T#{hours_minutes_seconds(video_length)}Z" )

# Lets print it out!
puts time.utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S") # 00:04:30
```

You could then store the value as the number of seconds [integer]. Getting a time object back from the length in seconds is easy.

```
puts Time.at(seconds).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S") # 00:04:30
```